# SQL update from one Table to another based on a two match keys

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I have two table:

first:

[image: tab1]

and the second

[image: tab2]

I want add the column value from second table to the value of first table where LocalizationFrontEndKey and language code are same.
How I can do this?

Comment: Plz mention your inputs

Answer (score 0):

use join

```
update  table1 t1 join table2 
on t1.localizationEndKey=t2.localizationEndKey 
and t1.language=t2.language
set t1.value=t2.value
```

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax to join multiple table in update is,

```
UPDATE T1   
SET T1.VALUE=T2.VALUE
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.LOCALIZATIONENDKEY=T2.LOCALIZATIONENDKEY
AND T1.LANGUAGE=T2.LANGUAG
```